# .htaccess alias URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, mod-alias

I am trying to create a redirect of a temp URL using

```
Redirect Permanent /dir/subdir http://www.domain.com/other_dir/htmlfile.html
```

Note that "dir" exists in the file structure but "subdir" does not.

In the browser if I type http://www.domain.com/dir/subdir the redirect works (even though, again, "subdir" does not exist) but http://www.domain.com/dir/subdir**/** returns a 404.

Basically I want to create a *fake* directory that redirects to a file

Answer (score 0):

It's not a directory vs. file thing. You may have any URL point to anything you want, Redirect Permament is pretty strict in this sense, so if you want /dir/subdir/ to work as well, you should declare another alias:
Redirect Permanent /dir/subdir/ http://www.domain.com/other_dir/htmlfile.html